# In maya, how to set parent joint without generating "transform node"

Tags: maya

see my gif
[image]

when I reparent hip object, it generated "transform1" in outliner, how to don't don't generate transform and just reparent one joint to an

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-animation-and-rigging/reparenting-joint-adds-extra-transform-node/td-p/5291227) is answer

if reparent targetobject generate 'transform node", hit 'z' to back to init status(not reparent status)

first, set targetobject's all ancestors(parent object, parent's parent object, ...)'s scale to 1,1,1, **attention, whatever old scale is 1 or not, you must do set scale 1 in Channel Box/Layer Editor**

see my gif, following is bug reproduce(without setting scale as 1)

[image]

following is done with setting scale as 1

[image]

**tip: since i rare modify skeleton so use gui operations is enough, if you often use it, maybe maya python script can do it with one cmd**

Answer (score 0):

You may get more/quicker answers on another forum as SO is strictly for programming questions.

This is likely because somewhere in your hierarchy from _root, it is scaled, which propagates down to your object. Then when you want to re-parent your object elsewhere it will create that unwanted transform to try and preserve its scale that was inherited.

The fix is simple but might require addition fixing depending on the complexity of your rig: you have to freeze scale on _root, then you should be able to re-parent afterwards without generating that new transform. Be warned, this may cause pops somewhere down the chain that may need fixing.

Let this be a lesson: scaling in rigging in any 3d software is evil for so many reasons. Just don't do it, unless it's there for some purpose. And if you do scale, clean it up before using it!

Comment: when i import exist model, channel box > right click > freeze > scale, will raise "Error: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/scripts/startup/channelBoxCommand.mel line 390: Freeze Transform was not applied because _root.scaleX has incoming connection", but my solution has not this error

Comment: Freeze transforms cannot be used if the channels already have drivers (anim curves, connection, constraint, etc..). So you would have to break connections. This is why it's best to clean the transforms sooner than later otherwise it creates more work for you.